# Find value in another workbook and copy specifiec cells from one row to many column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy, paste

I try to creat a Macro where select one value from the actieve workbook and search about it in another workbook then when find the value select the cells like array (after actieve cell move one cell to the right and select the cell then select another cell after 2 column and select Like: 
( C2,F2,I2,L2 ....).copy
and past it transpose in first workbook

maybe it's a little hard to explain but I think the code would be better:

```
Sub Find_copy_paste()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim x as Workbook

    Set y = Workbooks("H\Data1.xlsm")
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("G\info.xlsx")

    FindString = y.Sheets("Teams").Range("A121").Value

    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With x.Sheets("Claims").Range("B:B")
            Set Rng = .find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
            **'' I want hier to select actieve cell then one step to the right and start to copy array  ( C2,F2,I2,L2 ....) then paste it transpose in y workbook**

            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Any body can help??

Thanks :)

Comment: So if you find "Claims" you want to go one cell to the right and then copy every third cell? Until when - you run out of data or column L?

Comment: Yes, I wanna it untile colum 156, but I try to find code to select and copy this specific cells